# Rewriting PowerShell functions in C#

Tags: c#, powershell

I am currently rewriting a few PowerShell modules in C#, primarily to learn the language and get a grip on C# development. So far it has been going really well, with some 20 functions rewritten and tested.

One I'm stuck on is compressing a GZip string. I've managed to use functions written by others to complete the task, but I was (and still am) unable to directly translate my PowerShell function.

**Original PowerShell code:**

```
$ms = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$cs = New-Object System.IO.Compression.GZipStream($ms, [System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Compress)
$sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter($cs)
$sw.Write($StringToCompress)
$sw.Close();
[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($ms.ToArray()) | Out-File $FilePath -Force | Out-Null
$cs.Close();
$ms.Close();
```

**C# equivalent (Ignore void, was testing in LINQPad):**

```
public static void CompressString(string stringToCompress)
{
    var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    var compression = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true);
    var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(compression);

    Console.WriteLine("String to compress: " + stringToCompress);

    streamWriter.Write(stringToCompress);

    Console.WriteLine("Base64 encoded compressed string: " + 
    Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray()));
}
```

The PowerShell code works perfectly, yet the C# returns nothing. Why is this, as I believe my 'translation' is correct?

[image]

*Just a reminder, I have fixed my issue with help from another, but am now researching why the above did not work.*

Comment: `$sw.Close()` causes the stream writer to flush its buffer, but in the C# version you never close it - so by the time you call `memoryStream.ToArray()` there's no guarantee the writer has actually completed the write to the underlying stream

Comment: Goodness me... I thought the close method was just for clean-up purposes, I completely ignored it's position in the execution order. Thank you so much, I can finally get that out of my head. Time to read up on Streamwriter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, there's a slight difference between your two examples. The PowerShell version works because `$sw.Close()` causes the stream writer to flush its buffer before closing.

In the C# version you never close it - so by the time you call `memoryStream.ToArray()` there's no guarantee the writer has actually completed the write to the underlying stream.

The idiomatic approach in C# is to leverage `using()` statements for `IDisposable` resources, like so:

```cs
Console.WriteLine("String to compress: " + stringToCompress);
using(var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using(var compression = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
    using(var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(compression))
    {
        streamWriter.Write(stringToCompress);
    }

    Console.WriteLine("Base64 encoded compressed string: " + 
        Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray()));
}
```

In the above example, the `streamWriter` and `compression` stream will have been disposed of by the time you read from the memory stream, and by the time you return from the method the `memoryStream` will also be automatically disposed.